# How to solve the problem of building a project?

Tags: qt, qml

I reinstalled windows. And after that, the path to my project changed. Qt gives me a build error.

Cannot find file: C:\Users\...

I've tried deleting all past builds. And ".pro.user" files, but that didn't help either.

This is files.pro code.

```
QT += quick

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc \
    images.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

This is qml.qrc code.

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>Cell.qml</file>
        <file>SliderCell.qml</file>
        <file>Calendar1.qml</file>
        <file>Calendar2.qml</file>
        <file>FiltersCheckBox.qml</file>
        <file>DropDownListCell.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

This is error image.

[image]

Comment: You probably have to provide the *.pro file content at least.

Comment: I have added as you asked.

Comment: What is in the .qrc file?

Comment: Show the complete error message

Comment: I would strongly not recommend using non-English characters in the path

Comment: it says it can  not find .pro file which is so interesting. Can you open a simple qt example and try to run it ?

Comment: It gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of the folder. I was using russian symbols.

IF U HAVE THE SAME ERROR CHECK THE NAMES OF THE FOLDERS.